# Fonts not working in server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

my Fonts are placed in `app/assets/fonts/myfolder` & I can easily fetch them like
`src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url('myfolder/opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');`

It works in development env. For production , I have executed rake assets:precompile & then run the app. My fonts are loaded here as well.
But when I deploy my code to server, the fonts are not loaded.
I have tried `font-url(), assets-path, asset-url` but none works.